# VB to C# conversion of Byte

Tags: c#, vb.net, performance, type-conversion

Were taking some code from vb and converting it to C#. I have this line here:

```
Dim foo As Byte() = {155, 253, 147, 202, 22, 59, 228, 6, 61, 16, 158, 60, 47, 138, 40, 178}
```

and I am wanting to convert this to C# code.

but I know:

byte foo = {155, 253, 147, 202, 22, 59, 228, 6, 61, 16, 158, 60, 47, 138, 40, 178};

is not correct. Do you think anyone who provide me some insight on this and explain why the correct answer is the way that it is?

Comment: what research have you done in regards to a google search.. here is a great place to start [find how to do many things in C# .NET](http://www.google.com)

Comment: `Jimmie N` it's all good it just seems that individuals forget how to use the internet when it comes to something of this nature.. have a good day and remember `Googl is your best friend`

Comment: Microsoft should really get on the ball and put some authoritative guide of some sort on the web.  Maybe call it [Microsoft Developer something](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix I agree, they are all the ultimate end all, be all guide. I don't even know why Stack Overflow even exists :) but really, this was the quickest way for what I was trying to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an array. Initialize it like this:

```
byte[] foo = {155, 253, 147, 202, 22, 59, 228, 6, 61, 16, 158, 60, 47, 138, 40, 178};
```

Before you proceed much further, you should read the [documentation for arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx), or even a good text book. If you try to code in a language without sound knowledge of the fundamental syntax, you will inevitably write very poor code.